# How can I use a string array inside of an else-if to output an error or another type of message?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have the following application code that asks the user to input their weight and a planet name that they want to know how much they will weigh on.  However, the `if-else` statements keep outputting the same message for valid planets, why? How can I declare and initialize a string array that will check their input and then display the appropriate final message?

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;  

int main()
{ 
   int weight; 
   string planet; 
   double Mercury_Factor= 0.4155; 
   double Venus_Factor= 0.8975;
   double Earth_Factor= 1.0; 
   double Mars_Factor= 0.3507;
   double Jupiter_Factor= 2.5374;
   double Saturn_Factor= 1.0677; 
   double Uranus_Factor= 0.8947; 
   double Neptune_Factor= 1.1794;
   double Pluto_Factor= 0.0899;
   double weightOnPlanet;  
   string Mercury;
   string Venus;
   string Earth;
   string Mars;
   string Jupiter; 
   string Saturn; 
   string Uranus;
   string Neptune;
   string Pluto; 

   cout << "Assignment 5" << endl; 
   cout << "The program is written by Daron Seals" << endl; 
   cout << "\n"; 
   cout << "Please Enter Weight (as an integer of pounds): ";
   cin >> weight; 
   cout << "Please Enter Planet name (ie: Earth): "; 
   cin >> planet; 
   cout << "\n"; 
   cout << "You entered a weight of" << " " << weight << " " << "and a planet name of" << " " << planet << endl;

   if(planet== "Mercury") 
       weightOnPlanet= weight * Mercury_Factor;
   else 
     if(planet== "Venus")
      weightOnPlanet= weight * Venus_Factor;
   else 
     if(planet== "Earth")
      weightOnPlanet= weight * Earth_Factor;
   else 
     if(planet== "Mars")
      weightOnPlanet= weight * Mars_Factor; 
   else 
    if(planet== "Jupiter")
       weightOnPlanet= weight * Jupiter_Factor;
   else 
    if(planet== "Saturn")
      weightOnPlanet= weight * Saturn_Factor;
   else 
     if(planet== "Uranus")
       weightOnPlanet= weight * Uranus_Factor;
   else
     if(planet== "Neptune")
      weightOnPlanet= weight * Neptune_Factor;
   else 
     if(planet== "Pluto")
      weightOnPlanet= weight * Pluto_Factor;


      cerr << "Unknown Planet\n";  
// This is the final message that I want to display only if they input the wrong planet

    //  Then this message would be the final message that would display if they didn't input the wrong planet.
      cout << "On" << " " << planet << " " << "your weight in pounds would be" << " " << weightOnPlanet << endl;



     system ("pause"); 
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided your code. How do you expect us to help you? Edit your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: – Greg Kikola here it is above

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code always outputs the error message is because it is not inside of an `else` statement at the end of the list of `if` statements.  Try something more like this instead:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int main()
{ 
   const double Mercury_Factor = 0.4155; 
   const double Venus_Factor = 0.8975;
   const double Earth_Factor = 1.0; 
   const double Mars_Factor = 0.3507;
   const double Jupiter_Factor = 2.5374;
   const double Saturn_Factor = 1.0677; 
   const double Uranus_Factor = 0.8947; 
   const double Neptune_Factor = 1.1794;
   const double Pluto_Factor = 0.0899;

   int weight; 
   std::string planet; 
   double weightOnPlanet;  

   std::cout << "Assignment 5" << std::endl; 
   std::cout << "The program is written by Daron Seals" << std::endl; 
   std::cout << "\n"; 
   std::cout << "Please Enter Weight (as an integer of pounds): ";
   std::cin >> weight; 
   std::cout << "Please Enter Planet name (ie: Earth): "; 
   std::cin >> planet; 
   std::cout << "\n"; 
   std::cout << "You entered a weight of " << weight << " and a planet name of " << planet << std::endl;

   if (planet == "Mercury") 
      weightOnPlanet = weight * Mercury_Factor;
   else if (planet == "Venus")
      weightOnPlanet= weight * Venus_Factor;
   else if (planet == "Earth")
      weightOnPlanet = weight * Earth_Factor;
   else if (planet == "Mars")
      weightOnPlanet = weight * Mars_Factor; 
   else if (planet == "Jupiter")
      weightOnPlanet = weight * Jupiter_Factor;
   else if (planet == "Saturn")
      weightOnPlanet = weight * Saturn_Factor;
   else if (planet == "Uranus")
      weightOnPlanet= weight * Uranus_Factor;
   else if (planet == "Neptune")
      weightOnPlanet = weight * Neptune_Factor;
   else if (planet== "Pluto")
      weightOnPlanet = weight * Pluto_Factor;
   else // <-- ADD THIS!!!    
   {
      std::cerr << "Unknown Planet\n";  
      std::system("pause"); 
      return 0; 
   }

   std::cout << "On " << planet << " your weight in pounds would be " << weightOnPlanet << std::endl;

   std::system("pause"); 
   return 0; 
}
```

That being said, you should move the planetary values into an array that you can then loop through, eg:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

struct planetInfo
{
   const char* name; 
   double factor; 
};

const planetInfo planets[] = {
   {"Mercury", 0.4155},
   {"Venus", 0.8975},
   {"Earth", 1.0},
   {"Mars", 0.3507},
   {"Jupiter", 2.5374},
   {"Saturn", 1.0677},
   {"Uranus", 0.8947},
   {"Neptune", 1.1794},
   {"Pluto", 0.0899}
};

const int numPlanets = sizeof(planets) / sizeof(planets[0]);
// or: const int numPlanets = _countof(planets);

const planetInfo* findPlanet(const std::string &name)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < numPlanets; ++i)
   {
      if (name == planets[i].name) 
          return &planets[i];
   }
   return NULL;
}

int main()
{ 
   int weight; 
   std::string planet; 
   double weightOnPlanet;  

   std::cout << "Assignment 5" << std::endl; 
   std::cout << "The program is written by Daron Seals" << std::endl; 
   std::cout << "\n"; 
   std::cout << "Please Enter Weight (as an integer of pounds): ";
   std::cin >> weight; 
   std::cout << "Please Enter Planet name (ie: Earth): "; 
   std::cin >> planet; 
   std::cout << "\n"; 
   std::cout << "You entered a weight of " << weight << " and a planet name of " << planet << std::endl;

   const planetInfo *info = findPlanet(planet);
   if (info)
   {
      weightOnPlanet = weight * info->factor;
      std::cout << "On " << planet << " your weight in pounds would be " << weightOnPlanet << std::endl;
   }
   else
      std::cerr << "Unknown Planet\n";  

   std::system("pause"); 
   return 0;
}
```

And then you can replace the manual loop with the `std::find_if()` algorithm:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

struct planetInfo
{
   const char* name; 
   double factor; 
};

const planetInfo planets[] = {
   {"Mercury", 0.4155},
   {"Venus", 0.8975},
   {"Earth", 1.0},
   {"Mars", 0.3507},
   {"Jupiter", 2.5374},
   {"Saturn", 1.0677},
   {"Uranus", 0.8947},
   {"Neptune", 1.1794},
   {"Pluto", 0.0899}
};

const int numPlanets = sizeof(planets) / sizeof(planets[0]);
// or: const int numPlanets = _countof(planets);

struct isPlanet
{
    std::string m_name;

    isPlanet(const std::string &name) : m_name(name) {}

    bool operator()(const planetInfo &info)
    {
        return (m_name == info.name);
    }
};

const planetInfo* findPlanet(const std::string &name)
{
   const planetInfo *end = &planets[numPlanets];

   const planetInfo *found = std::find_if(planets, end, isPlanet(name));

   /* or, if using C++11 or later, get rid of the isPlanet
   struct above and use a lambda statement instead...

   auto found = std::find_if(planets, end,
      [name](const planetInfo &info){ return (name == info.name); });
   */

   if (found != end) return found;
   return NULL;
}

int main()
{ 
   int weight; 
   std::string planet; 
   double weightOnPlanet;  

   std::cout << "Assignment 5" << std::endl; 
   std::cout << "The program is written by Daron Seals" << std::endl; 
   std::cout << "\n"; 
   std::cout << "Please Enter Weight (as an integer of pounds): ";
   std::cin >> weight; 
   std::cout << "Please Enter Planet name (ie: Earth): "; 
   std::cin >> planet; 
   std::cout << "\n"; 
   std::cout << "You entered a weight of " << weight << " and a planet name of " << planet << std::endl;

   const planetInfo *info = findPlanet(planet);
   if (info)
   {
      weightOnPlanet = weight * info->factor;
      std::cout << "On " << planet << " your weight in pounds would be " << weightOnPlanet << std::endl;
   }
   else
      std::cerr << "Unknown Planet\n";  

   std::system("pause"); 
   return 0;
}
```

Or, you can get rid of the array altogether and use a `std::map` instead:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, double> factors;

int main()
{ 
   factors["Mercury"] = 0.4155;
   factors["Venus"] = 0.8975;
   factors["Earth"] = 1.0;
   factors["Mars"] = 0.3507;
   factors["Jupiter"] = 2.5374;
   factors["Saturn"] = 1.0677;
   factors["Uranus"] = 0.8947;
   factors["Neptune"] = 1.1794;
   factors["Pluto"] = 0.0899;

   /* or, to avoid the overhead of the operator[] searching for
   items you know don't exist yet, you can use insert() instead...

   factors.insert(std::make_pair("Mercury", 0.4155));
   factors.insert(std::make_pair("Venus", 0.8975));
   factors.insert(std::make_pair("Earth", 1.0));
   factors.insert(std::make_pair("Mars", 0.3507));
   factors.insert(std::make_pair("Jupiter", 2.5374));
   factors.insert(std::make_pair("Saturn", 1.0677));
   factors.insert(std::make_pair("Uranus", 0.8947));
   factors.insert(std::make_pair("Neptune", 1.1794));
   factors.insert(std::make_pair("Pluto", 0.0899));
   */

   int weight; 
   std::string planet; 
   double weightOnPlanet;  

   std::cout << "Assignment 5" << std::endl; 
   std::cout << "The program is written by Daron Seals" << std::endl; 
   std::cout << "\n"; 
   std::cout << "Please Enter Weight (as an integer of pounds): ";
   std::cin >> weight; 
   std::cout << "Please Enter Planet name (ie: Earth): "; 
   std::cin >> planet; 
   std::cout << "\n"; 
   std::cout << "You entered a weight of " << weight << " and a planet name of " << planet << std::endl;

   std::map<std::string, double>::iterator iter = factors.find(planet); 
   if (iter != factors.end())
   {
      weightOnPlanet = weight * iter->second;
      std::cout << "On " << planet << " your weight in pounds would be " << weightOnPlanet << std::endl;
   }
   else
      std::cerr << "Unknown Planet\n";  

   std::system("pause"); 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau  Can you tell me how I should go about it the way I presented it

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau  Yours too complex for a beginner c++ programmer

Comment: @DMicheal: I updated my answer. And if you don't want to be a beginner forever, I suggest you study the other approaches I described.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau  It's still has unknown planet when I input a valid planet

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau  I will

Comment: @DMicheal: Works fine for me. You must not be inputting planet name *EXACTLY* as they appear in the code. The `==` operator is a case-sensitive comparison.  If you want case-insensitive comparisons, you will have to write the constants in all-uppercase or all-lowercase, and then convert the input to match the same case using `std::toupper()` or `std::tolower()`. The STL does not have a function to convert an entire `std::string`, but you can use `std::transform()`, or just loop through the `std::string` characters manually in a loop.

Comment: Even better than a loop would be to use `std::map<string, double>`

Comment: @ Remy  I did that. I am typing as exactly how I have it in the code. Your code works by the way even though it's complex but it still works but my code doesn't

Comment: @DMicheal Why isn't your code the same as Remy's code?

Comment: @ Barmar I mean it's but I don't want too much complex code that I don't understand as a beginner learner in this programming language

Comment: @Remy Lebeau You have been a big help. I very much appreciate that. Thanks so much

Comment: @DMicheal: the examples I have given you all work fine for me, especially the first one (which is the one you are most interested in).  If it is not working for you then you are likely not integrating it into your code correctly.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau. It's okay I will try to figure out  the logic error on my own. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I finally did it. I had two versions of the same file. I update the other one and now it works perfectly. Thanks